# Trouble using Libelf/Elfio libraries : ELF not executable anymore

Tags: addition, executable, elf

I'm using Libelf and Elfio to try and add a new section to ELF files. I would like it to be executable, just like `.text`.

This is my problem : with Libelf, as soon as I load (`elf_begin()`), update (`elf_update()`) and release (`elf_end()`) my ELF, it stops to be executable (*seg fault* when launching). `readelf -S` displays the sections but returns also the error :

```
readelf: Warning: the .dynamic section is not contained within the dynamic segment
```

I didn't find any function in Libelf to "add" the `.dynamic` section to the `DYNAMIC` segment.

But I can do that with Elfio (with the `segment->add_section_index()` function), but then I have to manually add every other section to every other segment, as Elfio seems to overwrite them when loading the ELF.

Has anyone any experience with those libraries ?

My final goal is to be able to create a new executable section in the ELF, and modify its entry point to jump and execute directly that new section, in order to create a packer.

Answer (score 1):

Libelf does not manage the segments (i. e. the program header entries) of an executable ELF file. It does, however, by default re-layout the sections when you call `elf_update()`.

After the re-layout, the program header entries will most probably contain obsolete offsets.
The loader will then try (or refuse) to load sections from file offsets that were only correct before the edit.

Thus the error message: the .dynamic section is now at another offset in the file, and the loader notices that it is not in the DYNAMIC segment anymore.

You can tell Libelf that you are responsible for the section layout by calling `elf_flagelf(elf, ELF_C_SET, ELF_F_LAYOUT)`.

But then again, adding a new section will not be so easy anymore...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I'm able to re-layout the sections "by hand", it should work ?